# AD5933 analogs for 4-terminal measurements

Tags: analog, biopotential

I'm going to do bioimpedance measurements, and it seems that AD5933 chip (http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5933.pdf) has many useful features for this. However, every paper on bioimpedance measurement (e.g. Ishai et. al, Meas. Sci. Technol. 24, 102001) suggests to use 4-point scheme (i.e. 2 electrode for known current injection and 2 electrode for potential measurement). After examining AD5933 datasheet I find it difficult to use this part in 4-terminal setup, since AD5933 stabilizes voltage on the sample and measures current, while in 4-terminal setup it is necessary to have this the other way around.

May be there are any other reasonable chips, which are able to do 4-terminals, with the same capabilities for signal processing as AD5933?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://iopscience.iop.org/1742-6596/407/1/012019/pdf/1742-6596_407_1_012019.pdf is a paper you may not be able to get without being in a subscribing university, but you can try.  They add an analog front end to do what you're trying to do.  I'm including ref info and the abstract.

> **Interfacing the AD5933 for bio-impedance measurements with front ends providing galvanostatic or potentiostatic excitation**, Uwe
>   Pliquett, Andreas Barthel, Journal of Physics: Conference Series 407
>   (2012)
>
> Institut für Bioprozess- und Analysenmeßtechnik, Heilbad
>   Heiligenstadt, Germany Email: uwe.pliquett@iba-heiligenstadt.de
>   Abstract The AD5933 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ByS3O.jpg), a specialized single chip impedance analyzer,
>   made by Analog Devices, is basically not intended for use with four
>   electrode interface. Due to electrochemical phenomena at the
>   electrodes connecting the material under test (MUT), especially in the
>   low frequency region below 100 kHz, a two electrode interface
>   generates considerable errors during the measurement. Thus, for most
>   application in bio-impedance measurement only a four electrode
>   interface can guarantee reliable results. Here we show how a four
>   electrode interface with galvanostatic excitation but also for
>   potentiostatic excitation can be realized by just a few external
>   components.

A similar arrangement is shown at http://www.instructables.com/id/Body-Composition-using-BIA/?ALLSTEPS

[image: Instructables approach]
From the above instructables link